# A problem on measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $E_1$ and $E_2$ are a pair of compact sets in $\Bbb R^d$ with $E_1 \subset E_2$ and let $a=m(E_1)$ and $b=m(E_2)$. Prove that for any $c$ with $a <c <b$, there is a compact set $E$ with $E_1 \subset E \subset E_2$ and $m(E)=c$.

Defining a continuous function using $E_2 \setminus E_1$ which has positive measure (and using Intermediate Value Theorem) I have found a bounded set which satisfies the above property. How to make it closed ?

Comment: My approach:

Define the set $D_r(E_1) := \{x \in E_2 \vert d(x,E_1) \leq r\}$. Then $D_r(E_1)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^d$ for all $0 \leq r < \infty$ since $E_1$ is compact. It should be not hard to verify that $r \mapsto m(D_r(E_1))$ is continous.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what continuous function you're using here; without that information, I can't give you too specific of help.

However, I will remind you that if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function (between any topological spaces) then for any closed $A\subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $X$.  That might well be the ingredient you need!

If you can't see how to apply it in your case, please let me know what your function is, and we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a geometric approach: Take any hyperplane $H$ and move it in a parallel way until the measure of one of the closed halfspaces intersected with $E_2\backslash E_1$ has measure $c-\lambda(E_1)$. Then the set of all points in this set together with $E_1$ form a compact set with measure $c$. See the picture below.[image]

The orange subset $O$ of $E_2\backslash E_1$ can be chosen to have measure $c-\lambda(E_1)$. Clearly, $O$ is compact, so $O\cup E_1$ is compact too, $E_1\subseteq E_1\cup O$, and $\lambda(E_1\cup O)=c$.